# How to draw polygons around 3D coordinates while also wrapping round the box?

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, point, box

I have points plotted in 3D space, with four polygons that slice through the data cube at angles to the y and x axes.

I would like to, for each black data point in the box, work out the coordinates of the vertices of a square centred on the data point. Using these coordinates I can draw a polgyon, in the same way that I am doing now. The dimensions of this square would need to be the same as the width value defined on line 7. The square drawn must be inclined so it lies exactly on the existing plotted plane.

Does anybody know the best way to approach this? The other difficult thing would be that, if the square leaves the box, it should wrap round the other side of the box. The box can be stacked horizontallyand vertically with identical boxes, tiling infinitely.

My code can be found belw (sorry it's messy):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

angle = np.arctan2(1,4)
xangle = np.arctan2(1,4)
width = 100/np.cos(angle)
print 'angle:', angle*(180/np.pi)
print 'xangle:', xangle*(180/np.pi)
print 'width:', width

x1       = [0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50]
y1       = [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
z1       = [12.5,37.5,62.5,87.5,25,50,75,0]

x2   = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
y2   = [0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50]
z2  = [0,12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,0]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
#ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=90)
#ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1, zdir='z', s=20, c='g') 
ax.scatter(x2, y2, z2, zdir='z', s=20, c='r') #THESE ARE RICHARD'S COORDINATES notice how they do not lie on the plane

xa = [0,100,100,0]
ya = [0,0,100,100]
za = [0,-6.25,18.75,25]
verts = [zip(xa,ya,za)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xb = [0,100,100,0]
yb = [0,0,100,100]
zb = [25,-6.25+25,18.75+25,50]
verts = [zip(xb,yb,zb)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xc = [0,100,100,0]
yc = [0,0,100,100]
zc = [50,-6.25+25*2,18.75+25*2,75]
verts = [zip(xc,yc,zc)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xd = [0,100,100,0]
yd = [0,0,100,100]
zd = [75,-6.25+25*3,18.75+25*3,100]
verts = [zip(xd,yd,zd)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

#pyplot.show()     

x = [0]
y = [0]
z = [0]
for i in range(1,100):
    new_x = x[(len(x)-1)] + 50
    new_y = y[(len(y)-1)] + 12.5
    new_z = z[(len(z)-1)] 



    if new_x >= 100:
        new_x = new_x - 100
        new_z = new_z + 6.25
    if new_y >= 100:
        new_y = new_y - 100
    if new_z >= 100:
        new_z = new_z - 100

    if new_x == 0 and new_y == 0 and new_z == 0:
        print 'done!', i

    x.append(new_x)
    y.append(new_y)
    z.append(new_z)


ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=20, c='k', zorder=1)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Done! (Without wrapping around the box though..)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import random

angle = np.arctan2(1,4)
xangle = np.arctan2(1,4)
width = 100/np.cos(angle)
print 'angle:', angle*(180/np.pi)
print 'xangle:', xangle*(180/np.pi)
print 'width:', width

def totuple(a):
    try:
        return tuple(totuple(i) for i in a)
    except TypeError:
        return a

def plotSquare(ax,cx,cy,cz, yaw, pitch, diameter):

    colour1 = random.randint(0,255)/256.0
    colour2 = random.randint(0,255)/256.0
    colour3 = random.randint(0,255)/256.0

    centre = np.array([cx,cy,cz])
    radius = diameter/2
    #0,0,0 to 100,25,125 diff
    #100,25,125 /2
    #50,12.5,62.5 /50
    #1.0,0.25,1.25
    d1offset = np.array([np.cos(pitch)*radius,(np.cos(yaw)*radius)+(np.sin(pitch)*radius),np.sin(yaw)*radius])

    c1 = centre - d1offset
    c2 = centre + d1offset

    #100,0,25 to 0,25,100 diff
    #-100,25,75 /2
    #-50,12.5,37.5 /50
    #-1.0,0.25,0.75
    d2offset = np.array([-np.cos(yaw)*radius,(np.cos(pitch)*radius)-(np.sin(yaw)*radius),np.sin(pitch)*radius])

    c3 = centre - d2offset
    c4 = centre + d2offset

    verts = [[totuple(c1),totuple(c3),totuple(c2),totuple(c4)]]
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolors=[colour1,colour2,colour3])) 

x1       = [0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50]
y1       = [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
z1       = [12.5,37.5,62.5,87.5,25,50,75,0]

x2   = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
y2   = [0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50]
z2  = [0,12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,0]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
#ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=90)
#ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1, zdir='z', s=20, c='g') 
ax.scatter(x2, y2, z2, zdir='z', s=20, c='r') #EXISTING COORDINATES notice how they do not lie on the plane

xa = [0,100,100,0]
ya = [0,0,100,100]
za = [0,-6.25,18.75,25]
verts = [zip(xa,ya,za)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xb = [0,100,100,0]
yb = [0,0,100,100]
zb = [25,-6.25+25,18.75+25,50]
verts = [zip(xb,yb,zb)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xc = [0,100,100,0]
yc = [0,0,100,100]
zc = [50,-6.25+25*2,18.75+25*2,75]
verts = [zip(xc,yc,zc)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

xd = [0,100,100,0]
yd = [0,0,100,100]
zd = [75,-6.25+25*3,18.75+25*3,100]
verts = [zip(xd,yd,zd)]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts))

x = [0]
y = [0]
z = [0]
for i in range(1,100):
    new_x = x[(len(x)-1)] + 50
    new_y = y[(len(y)-1)] + 12.5
    new_z = z[(len(z)-1)] 

    if new_x >= 100:
        new_x = new_x - 100
        new_z = new_z + 6.25
        #new_y = new_y + (50-12.5)
    if new_y >= 100:
        new_y = new_y - 100
    if new_z >= 100:
        new_z = new_z - 100

    if new_x == 0 and new_y == 0 and new_z == 0:
        print 'done!', i

    x.append(new_x)
    y.append(new_y)
    z.append(new_z)


ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=20, c='k', zorder=1)

storedcoordinates = zip(x,y,z)
for x,y,z in storedcoordinates:
    plotSquare(ax,x,y,z,xangle,angle, width/2)

pyplot.show()
```